# Cron Job for deleting daily apache Log

Tags: apache-2.4, cron, log-files, ubuntu-18.04, cron.daily

on my Ubuntu cloud server often happens when i visit apache log fiiles to be 5-10 GB in a day or two, i'm a user of vestaCP and destination of log files is: var/log/apache/domains/domain.error.log and file domain.log

Also I have the same problem, for the directory /var/log/journal/system.journal growning to fast. 
is there any cron job that I can delete this files on daily automatic?

Best regards

Comment: what have you currently got (and why isn't it working?)

Comment: Logrotate is your friend

Comment: This is ok for the apache logs but how can I use it for /var/log/journal/system.journal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use integrated Logrotate solution, with low retention for automatic purge

Take a look in **/etc/logrotate.d/apache2**

Comment: This is ok for the apache logs but how can I use it for /var/log/journal/system.journal ?